# Designing Consistent Invoice Module

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, domain-model

I have come to a struggle to design invoice generator module in my project. I have following design;

[image]

Once an invoice is generated , it will be stored in database. In case user need to regenerate an invoice in the future and if product has been changed (e.g price), regenerated invoice will be different than the original one. My question is ; 
How can i design it so that , even product data changes , system will be able to regenerate same invoice of a the same purchase order ?

Comment: Take a look at CQRS (https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) then will talk. I don't want to write a very long answer but I will help you.

Comment: Does the re-generated invoice have to be identical to the original one, including any possible misspellings in the product name/description?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau  I believe so. I build this module for myself so I am the one who put that business rule. I think users should be able to re-generate exactly same invoice  if they need to. Any changes on product (name,price,tax...etc) should not make any changes on the original invoice.

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU I had a look on CQRS. Are you suggesting that CQRS is the solution to  this design? If so , can you briefly explain? Shall i do event sourcing to keep track of changes on product?

Comment: CQRS is perfect for the DDD aproach. Commands are sent to the Aggregates that publish domain events. In your case you could listen to the right event to update+regenerate the invoice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, products do not have prices, for the very reason you have come upon: prices can change.

Instead. a "product" table is going to be joined to an "offer" table which contains the price and a start and end date, as well as other potential rules (e.g. special sale conditions or vendor preference).

You can see this structure, for example, in the [Magento database schema](http://inchoo.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/MAGENTO_v1.3.2.4-Database_Diagram.pdf).  Magento is a very popular e-commerce platform that stores product prices in a table named `catalogrule_product_price`.  You'll notice the `catalog_product_entity` table doesn't contain price at all.

Invoice line items would link to an Offer.  An Offer's price can never change.  To change the price of a product, you'd add a new Offer to the product and expire the old one.  Links to the original offer would remain in place so invoice line items would stay intact and accurate.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to be able to recreate an invoice with the exact original contents at any time in the future, regardless of what happens with the contents of your database, then there are essentially two approaches you can take.

1. You design your database to be "add only": Existing records are never changed. If you need to change, for example, the price of a product, then you don't update the table record for that product but rather you add a new record for the product with the new price.
   If you have a lot of tables with links between them, then this scheme will cause a lot of cascading changes and you will need to think carefully about how you retrieve only the latest version of any item when doing a general query.
2. You duplicate the relevant product information in the InvoiceItem rows. Needing access to the data values as they were at a particular point in time can be a valid reason to de-normalize your database.

The bottom line is that you need to ensure that any updates to your database don't destroy the old data that might be needed for the invoice generation.

Comment: Had to make such a decision several times now. IMHO its always better to de-normalize historical data; never had larger issues with that because historical data should - by all means - be readonly. For invoices its especially important because, at least in some countries, the items on different versions of invoices or cancellations have to 100% identical **for legal reasons.**

Comment: What he said. Immutable history is impossible in practice unless that's the only way the DBMS works. The times I've done this we've copied data.

Comment: If  i choose to duplicate data in InvoiceItem entity, do i have to change my class design?

Comment: @BorisZolotov: That would be the easiest way, especially if you only need a subset of the Product properties for your InvoiceItem data.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Thanks.I believe, this way is simple and consistent without doing over-engineering.